# Python ctypes - Getting 0 with GetVersionEx function

Tags: python, windows, ctypes

**Explanation**: I'm trying to get the results of the function GetVersionEx, but I get '0' at the output all the time:

```
class op_info(Structure):
     _fields_ = [
        ('dwOSVersionInfoSize', DWORD),
        ('dwMajorVersion', DWORD),
        ('dwMinorVersion', DWORD),
        ('dwBuildNumber', DWORD),
        ('dwPlatformId', DWORD),
        ('szCSDVersion', DWORD)
     ]

def info():
    op = op_info()
    ctypes.windll.Kernel32.GetVersion(byref(op))
    return op.dwMajorVersion

print info()
```

**Question**: How can I make this function works and get real results?

**EDIT**: @eryksun I did this before I called to GetVersionExW function:

```
 import sys
 op.dwOSVersionInfoSize = sys.getsizeof(op_info)
```

and the output is: 452

But the final result of info() is still 0

Comment: You're calling `GetVersion` instead of [`GetVersionExW`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724451). Plus you haven't correctly defined the [`OSVERSIONINFO`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724834) struct; the `szCSDVersion` field should be a `WCHAR * 128` array. You also haven't set the `dwOSVersionInfoSize` field as described in the docs, e.g. `op.dwOSVersionInfoSize = sizeof(op_info)`. This is required because `GetVersionExW` can also fill in a larger [`OSVERSIONINFOEX`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724833) struct.

Comment: @eryksun Ok you're right, I'll try and let you know if I got it, Thank you anyway

Comment: @eryksun I dont understand where to declare dwOSVersionInfoSize

Comment: The value of the field gets assigned to the instance, not declared. You can override `__init__` to assign the size automatically.

Comment: Use `sizeof`, i.e. `ctypes.sizeof`. Also, please note that the call returns a `BOOL` result, which will be false if the call fails. In that case you can `raise ctypes.WinError()` to get an exception based on the last Windows error.

Comment: Thanks!!! You are the best. If you want do an answer and I'll mark you as the answer of this question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example setup for calling [`GetVersionExW`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724451) to fill in either an [`OSVERSIONINFO`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724834) or [`OSVERSIONINFOEX`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724833) record.

```
import ctypes
from ctypes.wintypes import BYTE, WORD, DWORD, WCHAR

kernel32 = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32', use_last_error=True)

class OSVERSIONINFO(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = (('dwOSVersionInfoSize', DWORD),
                ('dwMajorVersion',      DWORD),
                ('dwMinorVersion',      DWORD),
                ('dwBuildNumber',       DWORD),
                ('dwPlatformId',        DWORD),
                ('szCSDVersion',        WCHAR * 128))    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        super(OSVERSIONINFO, self).__init__(*args, **kwds)
        self.dwOSVersionInfoSize = ctypes.sizeof(self)
        kernel32.GetVersionExW(ctypes.byref(self))

class OSVERSIONINFOEX(OSVERSIONINFO):
    _fields_ = (('wServicePackMajor', WORD),
                ('wServicePackMinor', WORD),
                ('wSuiteMask',        WORD),
                ('wProductType',      BYTE),
                ('wReserved',         BYTE))

def errcheck_bool(result, func, args):
    if not result:
        raise ctypes.WinError(ctypes.get_last_error())
    return args

kernel32.GetVersionExW.errcheck = errcheck_bool
kernel32.GetVersionExW.argtypes = (ctypes.POINTER(OSVERSIONINFO),)

def get_os_major_version():
    info = OSVERSIONINFO()
    return info.dwMajorVersion
```

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print get_os_major_version()
```